# How to create function to use regular expressions to replace column names in a data frame?

Tags: r

I am feeling lost with how to create a helper function in R that takes the following 3 arguments:

- a data frame,
- a string pattern, and
- a string "replacement pattern".

The function is supposed to replace occurrences of the string pattern in the names of the variables in the data frame with the replacement pattern.

Any guidance, tips or help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

```r
func <- function(x, nm1, nm2, ...) {
  names(x) <- gsub(nm1, nm2, names(x), ...)
  x
}
head(func(mtcars, "c", "C"))
#                    mpg Cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qseC vs am gear Carb
# Mazda RX4         21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
# Mazda RX4 Wag     21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
# Datsun 710        22.8   4  108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
# Hornet 4 Drive    21.4   6  258 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
# Hornet Sportabout 18.7   8  360 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2
# Valiant           18.1   6  225 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1
```